# How do you update a Cassandra integer column using CQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table 'reviews' in Cassandra as mentioned below:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
  review_id text,
  downcount int,
  upcount int,
  creation_date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (review_id)
)
```

Lets say I want to increase the `upcount` value by 1, how can I do that in Cassandra CQL?

When I do:

```
UPDATE reviews SET upcount = upcount +1 WHERE review_id = '123456';
```

It gives me the below error:

> Bad Request: Invalid operation (`upcount = upcount + 1`) for non counter column `upcount`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use Cassandra's counter columns data type. Keep in mind you cannot mix counter columns with non-counter columns in the same column family if the non-counter columns are not part of the composite `PRIMARY KEY`. So you have to separate the counters into another column family, say `reviews_counts`.

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
  review_id text,
  creation_date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (review_id)
)

CREATE TABLE reviews_counts (
  review_id text,
  downcount counter,
  upcount counter,
  PRIMARY KEY (review_id)
)
```

Now the increment statement should work.

```
UPDATE keyspace.reviews_counts 
SET upcount = upcount + 1
WHERE review_id = '123456'
```

Here is some more documentation about Cassandra counter columns.
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Comment: I knew about the counters and just wanted to avoid that and see if there is any alternative.Anyways, will go and use this .Thanks for the reply.

Comment: One more naive question about cassandra, is it possible to define a primary key without the column being present in that column family,like you have defined primary key as review_id in review_counts table.

Comment: I do not believe so. Similarly to SQL, you cannot reference a foreign key in table `abc` without having the foreign key actually living in the table `abc`. Furthermore Cassandra organizes/replicates the data across the cluster based off the primary key, so I assume it would have to be there in the column family.

Comment: So review_id should be there in reviews_counts table.Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer,  you might want to change SET counter = upcount + 1 to SET upcount = upcount + 1.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do that. You have to read the column, update the value in application side and assign the updated value. As the error suggests, only counter columns support this feature in cassandra.

Reason is simple. Counters are synchronised across distributed nodes. Since cassandra ensures eventual consistency, updates on non counter columns might create a race condition on the server side.

Comment: Yes I wanted to avoid updating the value in application side ,because that will be an extra query to the database.Anyways thanks for providing useful information about consistency.

Comment: @tushR, actually, in Cassandra an `UPDATE` always create a new instance of the row you are updating, so in effect, you always read the existing row first... you only avoid the transfer of the data between you cassandra nodes and your client.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I ended up with a `set<uuid>` (e.g. ids of upvote and downvote  entities in your case). You can update collections similar to a `counter` but it's not required to be put in seperate table. My counter was basially the length of this set. In case you don't have uuids, even a `list<boolean>` where you add and remove element might work.
Of course, this isn't a universal solution and especially for high numbers inferior to counters, but maybe it helps in some other cases.