# How do I increment the value of a non-counter column in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

If I have an Account table with 2 columns such as:
`Account (id uuid, balance decimal)`

how can I achieve the following in Cassandra?

`update Account(id, balance) SET balance = balance + 20.0  WHERE id = 80327e25-c32d-4b23-9499-f7bbae76e799 IF balance < 100.0;`

I have a scenario where I would like to use Cassandra to keep track of balances in a cluster spanning 3 regional data-centers and be able to update the balance field with QUORUM consistency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you update a Cassandra integer column using CQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145817/how-do-you-update-a-cassandra-integer-column-using-cql)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that in CQL because it requires a read-before-write.

Instead, you need to perform this logic within your application by (1) reading the value of the column first then (2) setting the value with the `UPDATE` command. Cheers!

Comment: thanks. Is there a way (a mechanism or a pattern) to do (1) and (2) atomically?

Comment: Have a look at conditional updates (Cassandra lightweight transactions) -- https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html?hl=conditional#cqlUpdate__conditionally-updating-columns. However, I don't think this will completely solve your problem. Cheers!